# Parameter 0 of constructor in "" required a bean of type "" that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, pom.xml, lombok

The `@RestController` and its setup works well. I hit a snag when I was trying to add the service to the controller and auto-wiring them.

As far as I know everything looks like they've been wired well: it builds fine, and the IDE can't detect any problems. But I seem to be lacking something because it won't run.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.church.id.controller.ChapterController required a bean of type 'org.church.id.service.ChapterService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.church.id.service.ChapterService' in your configuration.
```

ChapterController.java

```
@RestController
@Log4j
public class ChapterController {

    @Getter
    private Map<Integer, Chapter> chapters;

    private ChapterService chapterService;

    @Autowired
    public ChapterController(ChapterService chapterService) {

        this.chapterService = chapterService;
    }

    public void loadChapters() throws SQLException {

        log.debug("Loading chapters...");

        if (chapters != null) {
            chapters.clear();
        }
        chapters = chapterService.findAll().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Chapter::getId, Function.identity()));
    }

    @GetMapping("/chapter/list")
    public String list() throws SQLException {

        if (chapters == null) {
            loadChapters();
        }
        return chapters.values().stream().map(Chapter::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
}
```

Inside my applicationContext.xml (My bad. I originally typed pom.xml)

```
    ...
    <bean id="chapterController" class="org.church.id.controller.ChapterController">
        <constructor-arg name="chapterService" ref="chapterService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="chapterService" class="org.church.id.service.impl.ChapterServiceImpl">
        <constructor-arg name="config" ref="dbConfig"/>
        <constructor-arg name="addressUtil" ref="addressUtil"/>
    </bean>
    ...
```

The real pom.xml

```
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
```

ChapterServiceImpl.java

```
@Log4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Service
public class ChapterServiceImpl implements ChapterService {

    private DBConfig config;

    private AddressUtil addressUtil;
    ...
}
```

ChapterService.java (Interface)

```
public interface ChapterService extends Service<Chapter> {

    Collection<Chapter> findByCountry(Country country) throws SQLException;
}
```

I've looked around here but the following have /not/ worked for me

- [x] Adding `(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` to `@SpringBootApplication`
- [x] Prepending `@Qualifier("chapterService")` to the constructor's param: `ChapterService chapterService`

Also to note:
I've modified it to have only a default constructor, but the same type of error happens when I try to inject through a setter. I don't know what's wrong. :(

EDIT:
MainClassController.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClassController {

    private ClassInfo model;

    private HashMap<Integer, String> classMap;

    public MainClassController() {
        loadData();
    }

    public void loadData() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(MainClassController.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user7294900 Thank you for your response. I tried your suggestion, but it would still give the same error :(

Comment: Your spring configuration XML doesn't belong in your pom.xml

Comment: You don't need to use XML configuration if you are using annotations. Can you add your main class to the question? Thanks.

Comment: 1. If you're putting your Spring bean config in the pom.xml, you have a long way to go.
2. It's almost 2022, no one uses Spring XML config anymore. A result of combining disparate internet searches, I presume?

Comment: @tgdavies Sorry bud, I mislabeled my applicationContext.xml as pom.xml.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Oh thank you for letting me know. I mislabeled, and have input the real pom.xml. :) If anything, since we're not using Spring XML anymore, I presume I should migrate to annotations only?

Comment: There are hundreds of "Getting Started" tutorials on Spring Boot, just follow a recent one and change the code according to your need.

Comment: This is a good place to start --> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-start

Comment: Thank you very much @JoãoDias!

Answer (score 0):

A little background: I started my project years ago, but got side tracked and now picking it up again.

What worked for me was starting with a base spring-boot project and adding my classes and fixing as I went.

As what [@JoãoDias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16572295/jo%C3%A3o-dias) linked in the comments: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-start is where I got my base spring boot. (Check Spring Initializr in the article).

Also advised by [@AbhijitSarkar](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/users/839733/abhijit-sarkar) was that "no one uses Spring XML config anymore" which actually is a reflection on when I started this project. Very perceptive too that he was able to get the hint that my problem was due to combined internet searches.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).